# Integrating two Projects of same Solution DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, project

I have one dll project (A) of plugin in visual studio solution. This means i have a solution with one dll project.

I want to make another project (B) which caters to some specific functionality of dll project. Final output is dll. So dll project (A) is my main project. new Project B uses some of the headers of the dll project (A).

How do i link them together ?

I tried adding references of A in B but that failed. When i just add header files in "Additional Include Directory" it gave linker errors because it could not find the cpp or definitions.

```
       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
```

I also have problem in setting the output format for B. should it be .lib ?

Would "Add Existing Items" is the only solution ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: What linker error you are getting?

Comment: I would say "Add Existing Items" but I guess you are looking for more elegant solution.